# How do i convert byte array to image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to convert byte array to image using Javascript for displaying it in frontend.
I am inserting an image into mysql database using blob. The image has been converted to byte array before saving.

And I'm retrieving all the table values using json array and displaying using javascript. In the json array i'am adding this image as bytearray also.

I am able to retrieve the other values, but not able to display this byte array as image.

How do i convert this byte array to an image in javascript so that i can display it using html?

**the code for the above:**

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {

                //Sets the Old Image to new New Image
                $('#itemImage').attr('src', e.target.result);

                //Create a canvas and draw image on Client Side to get the byte[] equivalent
                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                var imageElement = document.createElement("img");

                imageElement.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
                canvas.width = imageElement.width;
                canvas.height = imageElement.height;
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);
                var base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

                //Removes the Data Type Prefix 
                //And set the view model to the new value
                $scope.itemImage = base64Image.replace(/data:image\/jpeg;base64,/g, '');
            }

            //Renders Image on Page
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    };
```

Comment: There are [several questions and answers on this](/search?q=convert+byte+array+to+image+%5Bjavascript%5D); what **specifically** makes your question different?

Comment: Java != JavaScript, please don't tag-spam.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is small you can encode it in base 64 and put that as the src of an img tag.